# Cant figure out why 'TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)' error is occurring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

im trying to update a database table but i keep getting this error:

File "/Users/tom/Documents/Documentation/Code/currentcode.py", line 554, in revealmathstestresultsscreen
    [(avgpercentagescore), (numberoftestscompleted), (improveon), (studentusername), (mathstopic), (date)])
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

```
cursor.executescript('''UPDATE mathstopics 
                        SET avgpercentagescore = ?, numberoftestscompleted = ?, improveon = ?
                        WHERE studentusername = ? AND mathstopic = ? AND date = ?;) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
                        [(avgpercentagescore), (numberoftestscompleted), (improveon), (studentusername), (mathstopic), (date)])
        db.commit()
```

what have i done wrong here? what could i have done wrong?

all help would be appreciated. I cant figure out this problem :(

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `executescript()`? (Plus that SQL statement has... issues once you use the right method).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `cursor.execute` instead of `cursor.executescript`

Answer (score -2):

Your `executescript` expects one string query to be executed but you are providing 2 parameters the query and variables.
I suggest you create a string with the variables and then execute it using db.commit

Sample:

```
cursor.executescript('''UPDATE mathstopics 
    SET avgpercentagescore = {0}, numberoftestscompleted = {1}, improveon = {2}
    WHERE studentusername = {3} AND mathstopic = {4} AND date = {5};'''.format(avgpercentagescore,numberoftestscompleted, improveon,studentusername,mathstopic, date))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Or use a method that lets you bind values to parameters so you don't have to worry about errors from trying to embed strings directly in the statement, SQL injection, etc.

Comment: i tried that but got an 'sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: True' error - it may help to know that the improveon variabel = True. please help?!?